# How to prevent one service from changing the USERPROFILE environment variable for other services?

Tags: environment-variables, windows-xp-embedded

I am facing a problem on Windows XP with environment variables.

Scenario:   We have some services installed on an XP machine. These services have login accout set to the Local System acccount. Then we install another servoce with a new login user which is created during installation for the service. User has admin rights. The new service is started. We restart other services which were installed before, now if we check the environment variable `USERPROFILE` of other services, we find it changed to the new user created above instead of 'Local System'.

Why does it happen? Where is this `USERPROFILE` stored in the registry?

We don't want the `USERPROFILE` value for any other service to be changed. But it happens when we restart the new service with new user. I think it happens with any service on restart other than local system account.

Comment: Other point is ...if we restart a service with logOn account as local system account, then it doesn't refect USERPOFILE change untill system is rebooted.
is there any way to propogate those changes without restarting in XP?

Comment: Any reply for this ?